# Principal Component Analysis in java

Tags: java, multiplication, principal-components

I am trying to achieve multiplication in array for doing PCA in java

I calculated mean and substrtacted it from each x values.Next I need to find covarience

So inorder to find that I need to multiply all the combinations in a given array

```
 [a,b,c] --> (aa)(ab)(ac)(bb)(bc)(cc)
```

How to construct a matrix of all possible products?

Whether taking subset and multiplying solves the problem?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what's the problem? How to construct a matrix of all possible products?

Comment: You can use an already implemented solution like: https://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/wiki/PrincipleComponentAnalysisExample which you can modify to your needs.

Comment: yes how to construct a matrix of all possibilities

Comment: I would Like to do it from the scratch for learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are computing a matricial product. Say `A = [a, b, c]` (horizontal vector), you get an obviously symetric matrix by :

> M = <sup>t</sup>A . A

The upper part of the matrix is composed of all possible products.

```
aa ab ac
ba bb bc
ca cb cc
```

When computing, you can use the symetry :

```
for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<=i; j++) { // do not go up to len but stop at i ...
        // computations ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks . How to get that in same order (aa)(ab)(ac)(bb)(bc)(cc) ?

Comment: Simply changing the second loop with `for int j=i; i<len; j++)` should be enough ...